# Acer Laptop Ubuntu 15.04 will not connect to public wifi

Tags: wireless

Today I exchanged my other Acer for this Acer ES1-521-266z and installed Ubuntu 15.04 onto it. I am not able to connect to public WiFi here at the library. There isn't even an option to connect.I tried a few "fixes" but got nowhere. In fact the last "fix" seems to have removed the WiFi icon from the task bar. Please help if you can. Thank you in advance for any help attempted.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)